# Why Django stops execution if reverse relation does not exist?

Tags: python, django

I have a common situation: a User model and an Employee model which is related to User by one-to-one relation on user_id. My user model is customized and one of customizations is the method "is_employee":

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    def is_employee(self):
        print(self.id)
        print(self.employee is not None)
        return self.employee is not None
    is_employee.boolean = True
    is_employee.short_description = _('Employee status')


class Employee(AddressMixin, models.Model):
    user        = OneToOneField(User, 
                                primary_key=True, 
                                related_name='employee',
                                on_delete=CASCADE)
    phone_no    = models.CharField(max_length=20, 
                                   blank=True, 
                                   default='')
    mobile_no   = models.CharField(max_length=20, 
                                   blank=True, 
                                   default='')
```

I use `User.is_employee` in the admin site on `list_display`. The problem is that the function `User.is_employee` only returns a result if there is an Employee for that user. If there is not then it stops executing where it first meets the call `self.employee` ant thereby returns None. And here is what I see on the admin:
[Employee status for the last user last user is not False but None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bbp3d.png)

Sorry if the question was messy. I am quite new to Django and this is my first post on this site as well. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `self.employee` raises an `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception when there is not a related employee. In your case, the exception is being caught and `-` is being displayed in the table.

You can use `hasattr` to check whether the user has a related `employee` without raising an exception.

```
def is_employee(self):
    return hasattr(self, 'employee')
```

See the [docs on one-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships) for more info.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what i was missing! Thanks a lot!